# Drawing Generated Image Every Frame?

Tags: opengl

Well i have a texture that is generated every frame and I was wondering the best way to render it in opengl. It is simply pixel data that is generated on the cpu in rgba8 (32-bit, 8 bit for each component) format, I simply need to transfer it to the gpu and draw it onto the screen. I remember there being some sort of pixel buffer or frame buffer that does this without having to generate a new texture every frame in association with glTexImage2d?

Comment: only needs to be allocated one time after that you just need to upload it when it changes

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Which is every frame.

Comment: but it's not generating but copying

Comment: Well i've tried simply using glTexImage2D to "upload" the data, but it doesn't stick. It still keeps the original image's data.

Comment: On a side note no where have i ever said that glTexImage2D generates images... I said i have an external system, in which has no affiliation with OpenGL, that generates the image and that image is the one i need displayed using OpenGL. And by generate a new texture I mean the glGenTexture() function.

Comment: @user240713 Read your question again - the very last sentence *literally* says that you do not want to "generate a new texture every frame with `glTexImage2D`".

Comment: idk "with" doesn't imply "using explicitly". Inorder to generate a new texture you have to use glTexImage2d regardless or there isn't a texture to be displayed. I was thinking "glGenTexture with glTexImage2D".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pixel Buffer Objects do not change the fact that you need to call `glTexImage2D (...)` to (*re-*)allocate texture storage and copy your image. PBOs provide a means of asynchronous pixel transfer - basically making it so that a call to `glTexImage2D (...)` does not have to block until it finishes ***copying*** your memory from the client (CPU) to the server (GPU).

---

The only way this is really going to improve performance for you is if you map the memory in a PBO (Pixel *Unpack* Buffer) and write to that mapped memory every frame while you are computing the image on the CPU.

While that buffer is bound to `GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER`, call `glTexImage2D (...)` with **NULL** for the `data` parameter and this will upload your texture using memory that is ***already*** owned by the server, so it avoids an *immediate* client->server copy. You *might* get a marginal improvement in performance by doing this, but do not expect anything huge. It depends on how much work you do between the time you map/unmap the buffer's memory and when you upload the buffer to your texture and use said texture.

Moreover, if you call `glTexSubImage2D (...)` every frame instead of allocating new texture image storage by calling `glTexImage2D (...)` (do not worry -- the old storage is reclaimed when no pending command is using it anymore) you may introduce a new source of synchronization overhead that could reduce your performance. What you are looking for here is known as [***buffer object streaming***](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming).

***You are more likely to improve performance by using a pixel format that requires no conversion.*** Newer versions of GL (4.2+) let you query the optimal pixel transfer format using [`glGetInternalFormativ (...)`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Image_format_queries).

---

On a final, *mostly pedantic note*, `glTexImage2D (...)` *does not generate textures*. It allocates storage for their images and optionally transfers pixel data. Texture Objects (and OpenGL objects in general) are actually generated the first time they are ***bound*** (e.g. `glBindTexture (...)`). From that point on, `glTexImage2D (...)` merely manages the memory belonging to said texture object.

Comment: The problem is that I need to create a NEW texture every frame, i can't just call glTexImage2d when the texture is binded. I'm calling glTextImage2D after calling it but it it still only displays the initial image.

Comment: @user240713 You can call `glTexImage2D (...)` any time you want, not just when it is first created. Otherwise, I think I misunderstand what you are trying to do; why do you need to keep copies of your old frames around? You will eventually run out of memory on the GPU if you do that.

Comment: That's the thing, i don't need it. I've tried calling glTexImage2D but it doesn't update the texture. It works if I generate a new texture and reinitialize it.

Comment: Alright nvm, it works, idk what was happening before.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, but.... I am not even sure what the question was anymore ;) I originally thought you were concerned about the highest performance way of doing this. I just earned 15 reputation and I do not think I did anything to solve your problem, which feels weird to me. Maybe there is something else I can actually help you address?

Comment: Well i will look into the asynchronous method if i need it, right now it's too early to tell. But just to confirm, the pixel data that I generate on the cpu and need to transfer to the gpu is done before any drawing and it is the last thing I need to display on the screen. So i could use the PBO to asynchronously upload the data and do what ever drawing needs to be done before i need the texture?

Comment: @user240713 Yes, that is a good use-case for PBOs. They are most useful for image *downloads* from the GPU, but the description you just gave is one that would benefit from PBOs for *upload*.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman I'm using a 4096x2048 VP9 encoded video as a VR skybox via `texImage2D` in my project, and have run into a massive performance issue as `texImage2D` when called each frame to update the texture is eating 30-40ms each call. Do you have any advice that I can use to optimize the display of the video texture?